# R-how to match these two strings?

Tags: r

I have two columns of date strings with different sizes.

Suppose one column has strings of the form, a="3 Feb 2012"
 and other of the form b="Feb 3,2012"

I need entries which have the same date in both columns.

Answer (score 3):

We can convert to `Date` class using the `format` showed in the strings.

```
a1 <- as.Date(a, '%d %b %Y')
a1
#[1] "2012-02-03"

b1 <- as.Date(b, '%b %d,%Y')
b1
#[1] "2012-02-03"
```

and then use either `==` or `%in%` or `match` depending upon the need

```
a1 == b1
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or another option is from `lubridate` package

```
library(lubridate)
dmy(a)== mdy(b)
#[1] TRUE
```